# event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.4.1.min.js:73

Tags: jquery

I have created jquery model popup using asp.net . I'm getting error from chrome browser in the below.

> `event.returnValue` is deprecated. Please use the standard `event.preventDefault()` instead. jquery-1.4.1.min.js:73

Answer (score 1):

It's just what it sounds like. You've got a script that is using event.returnValue instead of event.preventDefault(). You're also using a fairly old version of jQuery. If you have the ability to upgrade, you should do so.